# Is there a way to get the PreparedStatement query from a PSQLException?

Tags: java, jersey

I'm using Jersey to create a RESTful API in where there is implemented an ExceptionMapper class to catch all errors.

```
public class ExceptionFilter implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable>{

    public Response toResponse(Throwable thrownable) {

      if(thrownable instanceof PSQLExeption) {

      System.out.print("Error: " + ((PSQLExeption)thrownable).getQuery());
      }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the query string from the exception?
Or maybe implement PreparedStatement and create a method in it to get the query string?

Comment: AFAIK this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you require the throwable to be PSQLException?

You can throw a CustomException during your execution of the DAO layer which contains the prepared statement, of which this class can interrogate for the originating SQL.

Comment: Throwable can be any type of Exception but what I'm looking for is to get the sql query string when Throwable is PSQLExeption,

Comment: Since the PSQLException does not appear to allow you to have access to the sql, my suggestion is to throw a custom exception that extends the PSQLException, ie: MyPSQLException. In this class you will include the sql and in your actual class that makes the database call, you will try/catch the call and fill the custom exception with the sql. You can not solve your problem merely by registering an exception mapper, you will need to appropriately throw a custom exception from your calling code.